# C shell script : how do I compare two strings?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csh

I'm a C shell user.

I've two files.

file 1:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

file 2:

```
A
C
B
D
E
```

I want to compare only `A-A`, `B-C`, `C-B`, `D-D`, `E-E` using a `for` loop.

If the strings match, then print "match".

The output would look like:

```
A A -> match
B C -> " "
C-B -> " "
D-D -> match
E-E -> match
```

How do I use the `for` loop?

Comment: note: not trying to start a flame war, and you can continue using the C Shell if you want, but it's generally recommended not to: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot. also, welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: Don't program in csh (or COBOL or [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language) ) if you can possibly avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample script that makes use of the command `paste` to collate the 2 files into a single list:

```
A-A
B-C
...
```

It then parses each combined string into it's 2 descrete parts, and stores them in variables `f1` and `f2`.

```
#!/bin/csh

foreach i (`paste -d"-" file1 file2`)
  set f1=`echo $i | cut -d"-" -f1`
  set f2=`echo $i | cut -d"-" -f2`
  if ($f1 == $f2) then
    echo "$f1 $f2 -> match"
  else
    echo "$f1 $f2 -> "'" "'
  endif
end
```

The rest of the code is standard C shell.

#### Example

```
$ ./cmd.csh
A A -> match
B C -> " "
C B -> " "
D D -> match
E E -> match
```

#### References

- [csh and tcsh scripts](http://faculty.plattsburgh.edu/jan.plaza/computing/help/tcsh.htm)
- [Looping through 2 files simultaneously](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/125677-looping-through-2-files-simultaneously.html)